# Bug when editing custom post type category?

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

When editing categories for my custom post type the selected admin menu is the one for posts (see screenshot). Is this a bug. If not it's kind of non intuitive, and not so good for the end users experience.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBQpb.png)

Code:

```
function product_register_product_post_type() {

    $box_post_type_args = array(
        'show_ui' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array(
            'product_category'
        ),
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail',
            'slug'
        ),
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Products',
            'singular_name' => 'Product',
            'add_new' => 'Add New Product',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
            'new_item' => 'New Product',
            'view_item' => 'View Product',
            'search_items' => 'Search Products',
            'not_found' => 'No Products Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products Found In Trash'
        ),
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'produkt' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'product', $box_post_type_args );

    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Category' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Genre Category' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Categories' ),
    );  

    register_taxonomy( 'product_category', array( 'product' ), array(
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'produkter' ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'product_register_product_post_type');
```

Comment: i do not think that wordpress supports custom categories just custom taxonomy and post types. I am sure there is a way to do custom categories but unfortunately i do not know how. It also might require a lot of coding

Comment: It works now. With the code posted above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a custom taxonomy and then add the name of the custom tax via the "taxonomies" arg when registering the custom post type.

Comment: I've done that. But the selected admin menu when I click my custom taxonomy is still "Categories" under posts.

Comment: How about posting your code? I'm not good at guessing...

Comment: (: Posted above.

Comment: Try moving the tax registration above the custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because you named your custom taxonomy "Categories"?

```
// Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        // ...
```

...

```
register_taxonomy( 'product_category', array( 'product' ), array(
        // ...
        'labels' => $labels,
```

Try changing the values in your `$labels` array that you pass to `register_taxonomy`.